# ng-csv $q.all add response to list angular

Tags: angularjs, q

I'm using the plug in [ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) for my angular project. I'm looping through an array and calling a `$http` get which returns some information for my csv file. 
I currently have it working for 1 result see below.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
    method: 'get',
    url: "[endpoint]user/212121"                                                
 }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var ur = data;
     deferred.resolve([{a:ur.accountId, b:ur.firstName, c:ur.email}]);
    })
return deferred.promise;
```

This will populate the csv with the one record. However Im struggling to get it to work with `$q.all`.

```
var queue=[];                    
$scope.testing.forEach(function(userjson){
 queue.push($http({
            method: 'get',
            url: "[endpoint]"+userjson.userId                                               
         }).then(function(response) {
             var ur = response.data;
                $scope.output.push({a:ur.accountId, b:ur.firstName, c:ur.email});
            }));
})

$q.all(queue).then(function(response) {
  return $scope.output;
 });

 return $q.defer();
```

When I debug `queue` it is full of promise objects that hold the `$http` data. Likewise `return $scope.output;` holds all the results. `ng-csv` doesn't seem to interpret it, I feel I'm close.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your then functions :

```
$http({
        method: 'get',
        url: "[endpoint]"+userjson.userId                                               
     }).then(function(response) {
         return {a:response.accountId, b:response.firstName, c:response.email};
        })
```

and :

```
$q.all(queue).then(function(response) {
   return response;
});
```

will be return an array of all response for each request.

Write your defer like this :

```
function getData() {
var queue=[];
var defered = $q.defer();
$scope.testing.forEach(function(userjson){
  queue.push($http({
        method: 'get',
        url: "[endpoint]"+userjson.userId                                               
     }).then(function(response) {
         return {a:response.accountId, b:response.firstName, c:response.email};
        }));
})

$q.all(queue).then(function(response) {
  return defered.resolve(response);
});
return defered.promise;
}
```

and use it like :

```
getData().then(function(data){ /*csv data is in data */ })
```

Comment: thanks, that worked in the sense that now response is populated with the correct data, so that very much for that. However on return $q.defer(); it is returning the csv before it gets to  $q.all. do you know how I can fix that?